# Redis master wipes out Redis slave data on restart

Tags: kubernetes, redis, master-slave

Sorry this is my first time working with Redis. I have a redis master deployment and a redis slave deployment (via K8s). The replication from master to slave is working as expected. However, when I kill the master altogether and bring it back up again, the sync wipes out the data of slave as well.

I have tried enabling `appendonly` on either and both but had no luck.

Question # 1: How can I preserve the data in slave when the master node comes back to life?
Question # 2: Is it a practice to sync data back from slave into master?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct practice would be to promote the slave to master and then slave the restarted node to it to sync the state. If you bring up an empty node that is declared as the master, the slave will faithfully replicate whatever is - or isn't - on it.

You can configure periodic saving to disk, so that you can restart a master node and have it load the state as of the last save to disk. You can also manually cause a save to disk via the SAVE command. See [the persistence chapter](https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/) in the manual. If you SAVE to disk, then immediately restart the master node, the state as saved to disk will be loaded back up. Any writes that occur between the last SAVE and node shutdown will be lost.

Along these lines, Redis HA is often done with [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/docs/management/sentinel/), which manages auto-promotion and discovery of master nodes within a replicated cluster, so that the cluster can survive and auto-heal from the loss of the current master. This lets slaves replicate from the active master, and on the loss of the master (or a network partition that causes a quorum of sentinels to lose visibility to the master), the Sentinel quorum will elect a new master and coordinate the re-slaving of other nodes to it for ensure uptime. This is an AP system, as Redis replication is eventually consistent, and therefore does have the potential to lose writes which are not replicated to a slave or flushed to disk before node shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem like this when i used docker swarm with ports in host mode. I had one master, one slave and 3 sentinel instances. There was a problem with firewall betwean containers on the same host. Redis sentinel didn't see redis db on the same host. So sentinels voted wrong when old master became alive and his old data were copied to another Redis.

I fixed it by allowing input traffic from docker_gwbridge interface